# Strong Convergence of Resolvents

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be an operator on a Banach space $X$. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ and let $(\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\rho(T)$. The following result is well known:

If $(\lambda - \lambda_n)R(\lambda_n, T) \to 0$ with respect to the operator norm, then $\lambda \in \rho(T)$.

However, I asked myself whether $(\lambda - \lambda_n)R(\lambda_n, T) x \to 0$ for all $x \in X$ is enough to deduce that $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. In this case, one knows that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \lVert (\lambda - \lambda_n)R(\lambda_n, T) \rVert < \infty$ by the uniform boundedness principle. Hence, there is $c > 0$ such that
$$\frac{\lvert \lambda - \lambda_n \rvert}{\operatorname{dist}(\lambda_n, \sigma(T))}  \leq \lVert (\lambda - \lambda_n)R(\lambda_n, T) \rVert \leq c < \infty $$
but that does not seems to be enough to deduce that $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. Maybe it is wrong but then I would like to now a counter example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there should be counterexamples: Let $X=l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $T:X \to X$ the left shift $Tx=(x_2,x_3,\dots)$. Then $\sigma(T) = \{\lambda  \in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda| \le 1\}$ and $T^kx \to 0$ $(k \to \infty)$ for all $x \in X$. Consider  $\lambda_n:=1+1/n \to 1=:\lambda \in \sigma(T)$. Now for each $x \in X$ we have
$$
(1-\lambda_n)R(\lambda_n,T)x= (1-\lambda_n)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{T^kx}{\lambda_n^{k+1}} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty):
$$
Fix $x$, let $\varepsilon >0$ and choose $m$ with $\|T^kx\| < \varepsilon$ $(k \ge m+1)$. Then
$$
(1-\lambda_n)\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{T^kx}{\lambda_n^{k+1}} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)
$$
and
$$
\|(1-\lambda_n)\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{T^kx}{\lambda_n^{k+1}} \| \le \varepsilon \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^{k+1}} =\varepsilon (1-1/n)^{-m-1}.
$$
Thus for $n$ sufficiently big
$$
\|(1-\lambda_n)R(\lambda_n,T)x\| < 2\varepsilon.
$$